# Stored procedure or 2 Insert statements?

Tags: database, entity-framework

I am not a DB expert and need opinions on how to design this better.

I have a table called `Achievements`. Each student will have a list of achievements (approx 100) and # of students will not exceed 2000. So we're talking about approx. 200,000 records eventually (assuming we don't purge).

I have a column in `Achievements` called `DaysCount` which will house only days count and we plan to reset it to 0 at end of the day. This is required as we want to know how many times a particular achievement was tried by a student for that day.

Now, after each `Achievement` is worked on, there will be 2 things to update:

1. Insert a row into `Transactional` table with Student Id, Teacher Id, Achievement Id... etc.
2. Update `DaysCount` and increment by 1 in `Achievement` table for that PK `Achievement Id`

Question:

1. Should I be calling `INSERT` and then `UPDATE` ?
2. OR should I use a stored procedure to perform `INSERT` and `UPDATE`?

Comment: Both ways work equally well - totally up to you. Important thing is: wrap those two statements into a **transaction** to either have both of them succeed - or rollback when one of them fails - in order to have consistent data. But if you're using Entity Framework already - I'd use the EF methods to handle this - why resort to raw SQL for this? Just do your `INSERT` and `UPDATE` on the EF level (with the involved **entities**)

Comment: Thanks...Yes I plan to use EF core as below then

                _context.trantable.Add(request.abc);  
                _context.achievements.Where(x=>x.Id == request.abc.Id).ExecuteUpdate(b=>b.SetProperty(u=>u.DayCount,request.abc.DayCount));
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

Comment: I just saw that .ExecuteUpdate is terminating. So, I guess SaveChangesAsync() is not required. How do I make it as a transaction then?

Comment: EF will run all necessary inserts and updates when calling `SaveChangesAsync()` as a transaction